# Disable UDP on raspberry pi and only use TCP

Tags: streaming-video

I'm currently doing video transmission through wifi and there is a lot of lag and distortions, is there a way where I can only use TCP and not UDP to do this video transmission?

Comment: What protocol are you using? Everything depends on that.

Comment: I am using RTSP

Comment: RTSP isn't a video streaming protocol, it's a control protocol for video streaming.  Your actual streaming protocol is probably either RTP (which can be used over TCP) or RDP (which appears to be UDP-only).  In any case, the answer depends on what software you're using, both to send the data and to receive it.

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange rpi. We probably need a lot more information to help you with this issue. Please describe your current set-up. What are you streaming from, what are you streaming to, what programs are you using on the different ends, what kind of wifi do you run and so forth.

Comment: Run it through wired connection.